# What exactly is happening when a class is required and a method within another method is invoked?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, constructor

When a method, such as `createServer()` in a Class is invoked as following:

```
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer();
server.listen(3000);
```

what exactly is happening?  If I'm understanding this correctly, the `http` class is a constructor and the require function instantiates `const http`.  `createServer()` is a method of the constructor `http` which is, in turn, invoked by `http.createServer()`.  The Node.js document shows that `createServer()` "returns a new instance of http.Server."

Does this mean `createServer()` works as a constructor as well and creates another instance within the already created instance? Oddly enough, `server.__proto__` points to the Function `setTimeOut`, not `createServer` nor `http`.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "constructor"? Because normally a constructor is what you *call* to make a  new instance. In JS normally you have constructor *functions* that you can invoke with the `new` keyword to get an instance, e.g., `new String("hello")` will make a new *object* (not primitive) instance of String. In more OO definition a constructor is a member of the *class* that allows you to make a new *instance* of said class. While it sounds like you call "constructor" something that is an *instance* that makes other instances. OO terms for that include "factory" or "builder".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require()` is a `function`, and is invoked with the `String` `"http"` here.
Node.js then looks for the `http` *module*, interprets it, and `require()` returns an `Object` with the exports of the given module. So a *module* is `require()`d, which can `export` multiple things, not just a `class`.

An `Object` in JavaScript is what in other languages is called a *'dictionary'* or a *'map'*, associating values to keys of type `String`. (`Map` was later added to JavaScript and can have keys of any type.)

`createServer()` is just a `function` in this `Object`, under the key `"createServer"`. When invoked, it returns another `Object`, an *instance* of `class http.Server`. It could be called a ***factory function***. See its implementation [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L38).

`listen()` in turn is similarly a `function` in that `Object`, in other words, a *method* of `class http.Server`.

Neither of these are *constructors*, which are invoked with the `new` keyword as in: `new http.Server()`.

```js
server.constructor === http.Server
```

Comment: When you say "an instance of class http.Server", doesn't class usually refer to a constructor function in JavaScript and an instance the inherited object?

Comment: `http.Server` is a constructor `function`, *aka* a `class`, yes. An instance refers to an `Object` that is the result of invoking a constructor, but that happens within the `createServer()` `function` here.

Comment: So even though http.Server is the constructor function, and createServer() is not, createServer() acts as a constructor for http.Server and returns the instance of http.Server?  Shouldn't http.Server create an instance of its own?

Comment: `createServer()` is just a `function` that [calls `new http.Server(...)`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L38), and returns the result. You can  use `new http.Server()` directly

Comment: @Kevvv do not misuse "constructor". It's a specific term, it doesn't just mean "a function that returns an object. Anything can return an object `function findUser(username) { return database.lookup(username) }` would return some sort of `User` object but that's *not* a constructor. A constructor you call with `new` to get an instance of a given class `new User("Bob")` would be calling the `User` constructor with the parameter `"Bob"` so you'd get an *instance* that is of type `User` and (presumably) the field `name` of that instance would be set to `"Bob"`.

Answer (score 2):

> What exactly is happening when a class is required?

First, **`http` is just a module not a class.** So if you are asking *What is happening when invoke `require()`*, it returns a reference exported module such as `http`.

> What is happening when a method within another method is invoked?

It depends on behavior of the method. In your case, `http.createServer()` returns the instance of `http.Server`. **That doesn't mean that `http.createServer()` is constructor of `http.Server`** but returns a instance of it.

```js
const http = require('http');
console.log(http.createServer() instanceof http.Server)
// true
```

Comment: What does it mean to return an instance of it without the constructor?

Comment: @Kevvv you misunderstand - `http.createServer` is *itself* not a constructor. It could still invoke a constructor internally. Or it might not - it might instead be calling a builder and *the builder* could be invoking a constructor. Or it might be returning a cached instance of a server so the constructor was invoked long ago. Or it might be giving you new instances via cloning objects, rather than creating new instances via a constructor. Regardless, `http.createServer()` is *not* a constructor, even if it gives you instances of a class.